# java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported

Tags: java, audio, ioexception

```
try {
    //String location = dir1.getCanonicalPath()+"\\app_yamb_test1\\mySound.au";
    //displayMessage(location);
    AudioInputStream audio2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("mySound.au"));
    Clip clip2 = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip2.open(audio2);
    clip2.start();
} catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException uae) {
    System.out.println(uae);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, uae.toString());
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't find it");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioe.toString());
} catch (LineUnavailableException lua) {
    System.out.println(lua);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lua.toString());
}
```

This code works fine when I run the application from netbeans. The sound plays and there are no exceptions. However, when I run it from the dist folder, the sound does not play and I get the `java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported` in my message dialog.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

The documentation for [`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) says:

> The implementation of this method may
>   require multiple parsers to examine
>   the stream to determine whether they
>   support it. These parsers must be able
>   to mark the stream, read enough data
>   to determine whether they support the
>   stream, and, if not, reset the
>   stream's read pointer to its original
>   position. If the input stream does not
>   support these operation, this method
>   may fail with an IOException.

Therefore, the stream you provide to this method must support the optional [mark/reset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#markSupported%28%29) functionality. Decorate your resource stream with a [`BufferedInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html).

```
//read audio data from whatever source (file/classloader/etc.)
InputStream audioSrc = getClass().getResourceAsStream("mySound.au");
//add buffer for mark/reset support
InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(audioSrc);
AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);
```

Comment: Ty, this worked. I modified the code like this:  

`BufferedInputStream myStream = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("mySound.au"));

AudioInputStream audio2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(myStream);`

  And now it works =)
P.S. if someone could format this comment it would be great =/

Comment: Is that what mark/reset signifies? a stream that can be seeked?
@McDowell, could you show the decorated code in your answer?

Comment: @Shurane - mark/reset lets a stream "unread" data back to the mark point when reset is called (typically by buffering data in RAM from when mark is called.)

Comment: Can't upvote this enough. Couldn't figure out why my audio wasn't loading properly from a file.

Since I'm loading from a file, it was easier for me to do this:
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(filename);
BufferedInputStream myStream = new BufferedInputStream(fs); 
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(myStream);

Comment: hey @SauceMaster I used this approach,because I am also trying to open a file,but still it does not compile. I am getting : "java.io.IOException: Stream closed". It seems to behave this way when it faces bitrates of 320kbps while in 112 it works fine.

Comment: @PotneySwitters I'm afraid I can't levy a good guess based on what you've said. Perhaps you could open a question here with some code and more explanation?

Comment: @SauceMaster, thanks for the reply. I gave up this approach because I couldnot get around this exception. I just convert everything to 112kbps and take it from there.

Comment: This solved the exception but now I am getting a "javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: file is not a supported file type" with a 16khz wav-file. Not sure if this has to do with the BufferedInputStream

Answer (score 6):

After floundering about for a while and referencing this page many times, I stumbled across [this](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~luv/teaching/COMP110/programs/AudioPlayer.java) which helped me with my problem. I was initially able to load a wav file, but subsequently only could play it once, because it could not rewind it due to the "mark/reset not supported" error. It was maddening.

The linked code reads an AudioInputStream from a file, then puts the AudioInputStream into a BufferedInputStream, then puts *that* back into the AudioInputStream like so:

```
audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename));
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(audioInputStream);
audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(bufferedInputStream, audioInputStream.getFormat(), audioInputStream.getFrameLength());
```

And then finally it converts the read data to a PCM encoding:

```
audioInputStream = convertToPCM(audioInputStream);
```

With convertToPCM defined as:

```
private static AudioInputStream convertToPCM(AudioInputStream audioInputStream)
    {
        AudioFormat m_format = audioInputStream.getFormat();

        if ((m_format.getEncoding() != AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED) &&
            (m_format.getEncoding() != AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED))
        {
            AudioFormat targetFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                m_format.getSampleRate(), 16,
                m_format.getChannels(), m_format.getChannels() * 2,
                m_format.getSampleRate(), m_format.isBigEndian());
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(targetFormat, audioInputStream);
    }

    return audioInputStream;
}
```

I believe they do this because BufferedInputStream handles mark/reset better than audioInputStream. Hope this helps somebody out there.

Comment: The other solutions here didn't work for my problem, but this one did! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just came across this question from someone else with the same problem who referenced it. Looks like this issue arose with Java 7.

[Oracle Bug database, #7095006](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7095006)

A test, executed when `InputStream` is the argument to the `getAudioInputStream()` method, is triggering the error. The existence of Mark/Reset capabilities in the audio resource file have no bearing on whether the `Clip` will load and play. Given that, there is no reason to prefer an `InputStream` as the argument, when a `URL` or `File` suffice.

If we substitute a `URL` as the argument, this needless test is not executed. Revising the OP code:

```
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource(fileName));
```

Details can be seen in the API, in the description text for the two forms.
[AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream(java.io.InputStream))

[AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(URL)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream(java.net.URL))

Comment: Where can I get AudioMixer? I tried a link you had in a similar post, but it directs somewhere else.

Comment: The mistaken reference to AudioMixer, a local class in one of my projects, has been edited out of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're input stream has to support the methods mark and reset. At least if mark is supported you can test with: [AudioInputStream#markSupported](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#markSupported%28%29).

So you should maybe use a different InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

I solved something similar and your code would look like this, it's up to you to try.

```java
try {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("mySound.au");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    Clip clip2 = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip2.open(bis);
    clip2.start();
} catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException uae) {
    System.out.println(uae);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, uae.toString());
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't find it");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ioe.toString());
} catch (LineUnavailableException lua) {
    System.out.println(lua);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lua.toString());
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and clarify / explain what is changed and why.

Answer (score -1):

I have made a perfect sound manager that implements McDowell's post.
`public static post SoundManager extends TylerTomas implements McDowell`

Here it is:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

/*To play sound:
Sound sound = new Sound("filename.wav");

sound.play();
 */

/**
 * Handles playing, stopping, and looping of sounds for the game.
 *
 * @author Tyler Tomas
 * @author Langdon Staab
 * InputStream method from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529754/java-io-ioexception-mark-reset-not-supported
 * It was posted by McDowell. THANK YOU SO MUCH.
 */

public class Sound {
    Clip clip;

    public Sound(String filename) {
        try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename)) {
            InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            try (AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn)) {
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioIn);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Malformed URL: " + e);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Unsupported Audio File: " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Input/Output Error: " + e);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Line Unavailable Exception Error: " + e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // play, stop, loop the sound clip
    }

    public void play() {
        clip.setFramePosition(0);  // Must always rewind!
        clip.start();
    }

    public void loop() {
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    public void stop() {
        clip.stop();
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return clip.getMicrosecondLength() > clip.getMicrosecondPosition();
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OP is asking a specific question about _their_ code. How does dumping your completely different implementation here help?

Comment: if someone asks "How do I fly from Toronto to Hamilton", You respond "take a cab instead".

Comment: I already did the work. Instead of everyone coding their own sound manager, they can just copy and paste this one into `Sound.java`.