# AudioSystem.getInputStream(InputStream) Exception

Tags: java, exception, audio, mp3, inputstream

I am trying to convert an `InputStream` containing data from an MP3 file to an `AudioInputStream` using the **Java Sound API**.

However, I keep encountering an `Exception` when I try to do so.

Here is the method that causes the issue:

```
public static int[][] getAmpFromInputStream(InputStream is) throws Exception{
    BufferedInputStream bs = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bs);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) (audioInputStream.getFrameLength()) * (audioInputStream.getFormat().getFrameSize())];
    audioInputStream.read(bytes);

    // Get amplitude values for each audio channel in an array.
    return getUnscaledAmplitude(bytes, 1);
}
```

The `Exception` that is thrown is:

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at PitchChanger.getAmpFromInputStream(PitchChanger.java:27)
    at GUI$PlayMP3Thread.silly(GUI.java:128)
    at GUI$PlayMP3Thread.run(GUI.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This confuses me however as I use the same `InputStream` to play into `Javazoom.jl.player.Player`, and it works fine there.

So why can't the `InputStream` be converted to an `AudioInputStream`?

Doesn't Java Sound support the MP3 file format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Exception Reading Stream from Resource .wav](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659842/java-exception-reading-stream-from-resource-wav)

Comment: I don't have access to the file in this case though, just the InputStream.

Comment: Java Sound does not support playing MP3 out of the box. You need a plugin for that. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392241/where-can-i-download-the-mp3plugin-jar-to-play-mp3s-in-java-code). The accepted answer has a link to download mp3 plugin. Get the jar and add it to your classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javazoom supports MP3 (has decoder) when AudioSystem must have RAW data provided (raw samples as in WAV format).

Comment: How can extract the RAW data from the InputStream then?

Comment: Depends what is it. Is it MP3 or what ? Generally you have to decode it. RAW data-decoded and uncompressed audio samples

Comment: It's an InputStream containing MP3 data.

Comment: Than get yourself some kind of mp3 decoding library, decode stream and play it than. Nothing to add more here i think, or just simply use jLayer. Here you havesample code of decoding MP3 frames using jLayer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099114/decoding-mp3-files-with-jlayer