# Access files (.wav) in Java package

Tags: java, audio, embedded-resource, javasound

I want to access my .wav files which are in a package inside my project.

For example I have two packages:

- `program`
- `sounds`

From inside the `program/something.class` I'd like to play the `sounds/asound.wav`.
How is this possible?

```
clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename)));
clip.start();
//.... something inbetween
clip.stop();
```

Here `filename` is `C:\\projects\\something\\sounds\\`, but how is it possible to just give a relative path to the `asound.wav` in the package?

Comment: Still doesn't work. For some reason I get a `NullPointerException` at the `getResource`. It is there, the file exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` to load resources via the same infrastructure you are using for class loading. Depending on the class loader, this can be a file in a directory, the content of a local JAR file or a remote resource.

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("asound.wav");
```

As indicated by the name of the method, you will get an `InputStream` for the resource, and not a File. If you consider that the resource may be part of another file, such as a JAR file, this makes sense, as File objects always point to single files, and not parts of them.

Comment: `getResourceAsStream(..)` will typically fail with Java Sound.  It seems to need an `InputStream` that can be repositioned, while the stream returned from `getResourceAsStream(..)` is typically not able to.

Comment: You can access the code at: https://bitbucket.org/eXor/starcraft-2-talk/src/02207cf263f8e6ec0a4fbbca47260cf0d6bc7a07/starcraft_2_talk/GameCounter.java?at=master#cl-108

Answer (score 1):

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/sounds/asound.wav");
```

The `/` prefix when supplied to the class-loader obtained from the class, will cause it to search from the 'root' of the packages.

---

Then see the code shown on the [Java Sound tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for loading a `Clip` and playing it.

Answer (score 1):

As also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529754/java-io-ioexception-mark-reset-not-supported/5529906#5529906): the documentation for [`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) says:

> The implementation of this method may
>   require multiple parsers to examine
>   the stream to determine whether they
>   support it. These parsers must be able
>   to mark the stream, read enough data
>   to determine whether they support the
>   stream, and, if not, reset the
>   stream's read pointer to its original
>   position. If the input stream does not
>   support these operation, this method
>   may fail with an IOException.

Therefore the solution will be

```
clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
    new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Sounds/asound.wav"))));
```