# java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported

Tags: java, audio, input, jframe, playback

This code does not work. I took a class ready since it can be found [here](http://javafree.uol.com.br/topic-879623-Executar-wav.html), but the music does not work. How can I fix this?

```
private void lblCliqueMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                     
     lblClique.setText("achou");
     musica = new Som();
     boolean repetir = false; 
     FileInputStream arquivo = null;
     try {
         arquivo = new FileInputStream("musica.mp3");
     } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(TelaProjeto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
     musica.tocar(arquivo, repetir);
}
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Also provide a more specific problem description than "Doesn't work".

Comment: A quick Google shows me [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529754/java-io-ioexception-mark-reset-not-supported).

Answer (score 11):

The error mark/reset not supported means the input stream you provided does not support setting a mark and resetting the stream to that mark. To achieve this, just wrap your FileInputStream inside a BufferedInputStream (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html)

```
InputStream arquivo=null;
...
arquivo=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(...));
```