# Groovy StreamingTemplateEngine IOException: mark() not supported

Tags: java, templates, groovy

Since now I used the `SimpleTemplateEngine` for processing my templates. I get the template files from a `JarFile` and create the template with a reader like this:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry), "UTF-8");
Template template = engine.createTemplate(reader);
String fileString = template.make(model).toString();
```

This was working fine, but now I need to create a template from a larger file and so the `SimpleTemplateEngine` can't handle this because it is limited to ~64K.

> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script
>   (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions
>   not currently supported): startup failed:
>   SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy: 5614: String too long. The given string
>   is 298596 Unicode code units long, but only a maximum of 65535 is
>   allowed.

In [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html) it says `SimpleTemplateEngine` and `StreamingTemplateEngine` are working identical but for Strings > 64K. When I switch the Engine I get this error:

**Edit stacktrace:**

```
java.io.IOException: mark() not supported
        at java.io.Reader.mark(Reader.java:232) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine$StreamingTemplate.handleEscaping(StreamingTemplateEngine.java:556) ~[groovy-templates-2.5.7.jar!/:2.5.7]
        at groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine$StreamingTemplate.<init>(StreamingTemplateEngine.java:460) ~[groovy-templates-2.5.7.jar!/:2.5.7]
        at groovy.text.StreamingTemplateEngine.createTemplate(StreamingTemplateEngine.java:215) ~[groovy-templates-2.5.7.jar!/:2.5.7]
```

Do I have to read the jarFile differently or how do I get rid of this error?

Comment: What is in `GeneratorIntegrationTest.groovy:206`?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529754/java-io-ioexception-mark-reset-not-supported - maybe you need a buffered is to wrap your resource.

Comment: @cfrick this is my groovy test that triggered the template creation. I already tried this but without success

Comment: Please show us the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to read the jarFile differently or how do I get rid of this error?

It looks like the `InputStream` that is returned by `ZipFile::getInputStream` does not implement mark / reset.

However, there is an easy fix.  If you wrap the stream in a `BufferedInputStream` the latter will implement mark / reset for the data in the buffer.  And you if you set the buffer to the size of the ZipEntry, you can buffer the entire stream; e.g.

```
int size = jarEntry.getSize();  // Might return -1.
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(jarEntry.getInputStream(),
                                                  Math.max(size, 8192))
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(bis, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: The `BufferedInputStream` is not the solution for me. After looking in the source files of `Reader` itself, I see that the `InputStreamReader` does not implement the `mark()` Method. The super class `Reader` has a method that only throws the `IOException`.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I got on the right track. I will add an answer with the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `InputStreamReader`. This reader does not implement the `mark()` method. I thought it was inherited from `java.io.Reader`. But after looking in the source of `Reader` I saw that there is a `mark()` method that only throws an exception. The `InputStreamReader` doesn't override it.

So I created a `BufferedReader` from the `InputStreamReader` like this and it works again:

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry), "UTF-8"));
```