# Java app cant find files after building it into a .jar in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, build, jar

I programmed an app that displays images and plays sounds.
That's why it needs to load images and sounds from a folder called "recources" that is located in the src folder of the project.

For the **images** I'm using the **following code** to **load** the png and then **display** it on my frame:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/recources/img.png"));
```

That works fine for running the app inside Netbeans and also after I built it into a jar.

The **sounds** are being **loaded** like that:

```
public Sound(){

    try
    {

        File audiodata = new File("/recources/audio.wav");
        if(audiodata.exists()){
            audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audiodata);

            clip= AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInput);
            clip.start();

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That also **works inside Netbeans** but **does not** in the **finished jar**.
--> NullPointerException

What do I need to change in my code?

What also doesnt work:

I also want to load a **sqllite database** with a jdbc driver with this code:

```
public void getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Lagerverwaltung.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:recources/database.db");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Lagerverwaltung.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

It has the same issue, when I run it in Netbeans it finds the database but in the built jar its not found.

I added the resources folder as a source to the properties of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the sound class to:

```
public Sound(){

    try
    {

        File audiodata = new File(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/recources/audio.wav").toString());
        if(audiodatei.exists()){
            audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audiodata);

            clip= AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInput);
            clip.start();

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and getConnnection to:

```
public void getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Lagerverwaltung.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/recources/database.db").toString());
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Lagerverwaltung.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Just changed how the file is being accessed. Hope it works. Do tell the result.

Comment: "this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/recources/database.db").toString()" gives an error: "non-static  variable this cannot be referenced from a static context".
I also added it to the sound class and there it gives a NullPointerException when run.

Comment: Wait it gives the NullPointer when I run clip.stop() in the sound class and not while loading or when doing clip.start(). If I change the url to a wrong url it gives it while loading the file, so the loading functions but the clip is not working anymore.

Comment: UPDATE: I got the sound to work with this solution: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529754/java-io-ioexception-mark-reset-not-supported)

Comment: Ok Nice you got the solution :)