# How to play an MP3 file stored in resources folder in Kotlin Multiplatform with Jetpack Compose for Desktop?

Tags: audio, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-desktop

I'm trying to play a sound in my Compose for Desktop project when pressing a button. My MP3 file is stored in the resources folder (./src/jvmMain/resources/beep.mp3).

I've been trying using the `useResource` function as follows (inside `onClick` parameter of a @Composable Button):

```
scope.launch {
 useResource("beep.mp3") {
                        val clip = AudioSystem.getClip()
                        val audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                            it
                        )
                        clip.open(audioInputStream)
                        clip.start()
                    }
}
```

but I get an error: *Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported*. I got the same error if I don't use the `scope`, which I define at the top level of my composable as:

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It looks quite simillar to this one issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/5529906/11207039. Does this solution work for you?

Comment: It works but only with WAV files, not MP3 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library is needed to decode MP3 files. This is the key. You may add this maven dependency:

```
implementation("com.googlecode.soundlibs:mp3spi:1.9.5.4")
```

Using Java Sound APIs you originally used:

```
import java.io.File
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine

class AudioPlayer {
    fun play(path: String) {
        val file = File(path)
        getAudioInputStream(file).use { `in` ->
            val outFormat = getOutFormat(`in`.format)
            val info = Info(SourceDataLine::class.java, outFormat)
            AudioSystem.getLine(info).use { line ->
                (line as? SourceDataLine)?.let { l ->
                    l.open(outFormat)
                    l.start()
                    stream(getAudioInputStream(outFormat, `in`), l)
                    l.drain()
                    l.stop()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getOutFormat(inFormat: AudioFormat): AudioFormat {
        val ch = inFormat.channels
        val rate = inFormat.sampleRate
        return AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, rate, 16, ch, ch * 2, rate, false)
    }

    private fun stream(`in`: AudioInputStream, line: SourceDataLine) {
        val buffer = ByteArray(65536)
        var n = 0
        while (n != -1) {
            line.write(buffer, 0, n)
            n = `in`.read(buffer, 0, buffer.size)
        }
    }
}
```

And call the `play` method from a non-UI thread / coroutine:

```
AudioPlayer().play(fullPathToMP3File)
```

Credit to original work by oldo: https://odoepner.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/play-mp3-or-ogg-using-javax-sound-sampled-mp3spi-vorbisspi/